# Unhandled exception with cudaMemcpy2D

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am new to C++ (aswell as Cuda and OpenCV), so I am sorry for any mistakes on my side.
I have an existing code that uses Cuda. Recently it worked with .png (that was decoded) as an input but now I use a camera to generate live images. These images are the new input for the code. Here it is:

```
using namespace cv;

INT height = 2160;
INT width = 3840;
Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC3);
size_t pitch;
uint8_t* image_gpu;

// capture image
VideoCapture camera(0);
camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
camera.read(image);

// here I checked if image is definitly still a CV_8UC3 Mat with the initial height and width; and it is

cudaMallocPitch(&image_gpu, &pitch, width * 4, height);

// here I use cv::Mat::data to get the pointer to the data of the image:
cudaMemcpy2D(image_gpu, pitch, image.data, width*4, width*4, height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The code compiles but I get an "Exception Thrown" at the last line (cudaMemcpy2D) with the following error code:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE838D6660 (nvcuda.dll) in realtime.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001113AE10000.

Google did not give me an answer and I do not know ho to proceed from here on.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Shouldn't the source pitch (the 4th parameter) be `width` here?

Comment: Why multiply times 4 if your pixel type is `CV_8UC3`, so 3 channels? Please verify that your total matrix data length is in fact `width*height*3`. Also did you check `cudaMallocPitch` return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather generic way to copy an OpenCV Mat to the device memory allocated using `cudaMallocPitch` is to utilize the `step` member of the `Mat` object. Also, while allocating device memory, you must have a visual intuition in mind that how the device memory will be allocated and how the `Mat` object will be copied to it. Here is a simple example demonstrating the procedure for a video frame captured using `VideoCapture`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

size_t getPixelBytes(int type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case CV_8UC1:
        case CV_8UC3:
            return sizeof(uint8_t);
            break;
        case CV_16UC1:
        case CV_16UC3:
            return sizeof(uint16_t);
            break;
        case CV_32FC1:
        case CV_32FC3:
            return sizeof(float);
            break;
        case CV_64FC1:
        case CV_64FC3:
            return sizeof(double);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    cv::Mat frame;

    if(cap.grab())
    {
        cap.retrieve(frame);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Cannot read video"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t* gpu_image;
    size_t gpu_pitch;

    //Get number of bytes occupied by a single pixel. Although VideoCapture mostly returns CV_8UC3 type frame thus pixelBytes is 1 , but just in case.
    size_t pixelBytes = getPixelBytes(frame.type());

    //Number of actual data bytes occupied by a row.
    size_t frameRowBytes = frame.cols * frame.channels * pixelBytes;

    //Allocate pitch linear memory on device
    cudaMallocPitch(&gpu_image, &gpu_pitch, frameRowBytes , frame.rows);

    //Copy memory from frame to device mempry
    cudaMemcpy2D(gpu_image, gpu_pitch, frame.ptr(), frame.step, frameRowBytes, frame.rows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   //Rest of the code ...
   return 0;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** 
Code is written in the browser. Not tested yet. Please add [CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/1231073) as required