# C++: Get BGR image (cv::Mat) from GPU memory (cudaMemcpy2D)

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am working on image processing and developed camera wrappers with OpenCV for a RGB and a monochrome camera. Now I have to use an existing algorithm that works with CUDA to process those two camera image streams. For that I have to copy the Mat images to my device (the algorithm does not take gpumat). I use `cv::Mat::ptr` to access the data of the images. When I use `cudaMemcpy2D` to get the image back to the host, I receive a dark image (zeros only) for the RGB image. Even when I use `cudaMemcpy2D` to just load it to the device and bring it back in the next step with `cudaMemcpy2D` it won't work (by that I mean I don't do any image processing in between). It works fine for the mono image though:

```
width = 1920; (image dimensions are the same for mono and BGR)
height = 1080;
Mat mat_mono(height, width, CV_8UC1);
Mat mat_mono_disp(height, width, CV_8UC1);
size_t pitch_mono;
uint8_t* image_mono_gpu,
size_t matrixLenMono = width;

cudaMallocPitch(&image_mono_gpu, &pitch_mono, width, height);

mat_mono = MonoCamera.CaptureMat(1); // wrapper for the mono camera that grabs the image

// copy to device
cudaMemcpy2D(image_mono_gpu, pitch_mono, mat_mono.ptr(), width, matrixLenMono, height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// copy back to host
cudaMemcpy2D(mat_mono_disp.ptr(), matrixLenMono, image_mono_gpu, pitch_mono, matrixLenMono, height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display window", mat_mono_disp);
```

This is the code for the RGB (or rather BGR) image, where I only receive a dark image after retrieving the image from the device:

```
Mat mat_BGR(height, width, CV_8UC3);
Mat mat_BGR_disp(height, width, CV_8UC3);
size_t pitch_BGR;
uint8_t* image_BGR_gpu,
size_t matrixLenBGR = width * 3;

cudaMallocPitch(&image_BGR_gpu, &pitch_BGR, matrixLenBGR, height);

mat_BGR = RGBCamera.CaptureMat(1); // wrapper for the RGB camera that grabs the image

// copy to device
cudaMemcpy2D(image_BGR_gpu, pitch_BGR, mat_BGR.ptr(), width, matrixLenBGR, height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// copy back to host
cudaMemcpy2D(mat_BGR_disp.ptr(), matrixLenBGR, image_BGR_gpu, pitch_BGR, matrixLenBGR, height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display window", mat_BGR_disp);
```

Does this mean that using `cv::Mat:ptr` with a mono image works as this is a special case? I don't know what I have to consider additionally when using the BGR image instead.

Comment: Use `mat_BGR.step` instead of `width` in the 4th argument of `cudaMemcpy2D` when copying the `Mat` to device.

Comment: @sgarizvi: That would be a perfect short answer to this question if you care to add it

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the solution! @sgarizvi

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824007/1231073), when performing 2D memory copy of OpenCV Mat to device memory allocated using `cudaMallocPitch` ( or any [strided 2D memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride) ), we have to use the `step` member of the OpenCV Mat to specify the alignment of each row.

In the provided code, the correct way would be to use `mat_BGR.step` instead of `width` in the 4th argument of `cudaMemcpy2D`.

```
cudaMemcpy2D(image_BGR_gpu, pitch_BGR, mat_BGR.ptr(), mat_BGR.step, matrixLenBGR, height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                                                              ^^^^
```